# Woocommerce replace product page image with product tabs

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have removed the product image on the product page using

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );
```

Now how do I move the product description or the tabs into that spot?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I hope anyways.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 20 );

remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 );
```